# Close secoundary database connection

Tags: mysql

I have two website. first one is in wordpress and second one is in corephp.
My Question is that i am connection database by $wpdb.

/* Core php database */

$newwpdb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );

Database connection is done. Now i am fetching some data using second database. After fetching i want to close the connection of core php database.

I have checked but not found any solution of it.
[Database connection close](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117495/database-connection-close)

So anybody knows than please help me for solution.

Thanking in advance

Comment: That link does give the answer. It says to use `@mysql_close($newwpdb->dbh)` to close connection.

Comment: But its not working. @mysql_close($newwpdb->dbh) close the connection of wordpress as well.

Comment: That should work and this seems to be exact duplicate to the question you are linked to. Please double check your code. Note that [different API might be used](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158425/847).